# how to use php code in javascript using laravel database

Tags: javascript, laravel

How to use this code in javascript lan and lng   `{{ $data->latitude }}`, `{{ $data->longitude }}` in this function

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat:, lng: },
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:

```
var latInfo = '{{ $data->latitude }}';
var lngInfo = '{{ $data->longitude }}';
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat:latInfo, lng:lngInfo},
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
```

Answer (score 3):

Good practice is to pass serialized or raw data to some element, for example hidden input:

```
{!! Form::hidden('lat', $lat) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('lng', $lng) !!}
```

And then get it with JS from these elements. jQuery example:

```
var lat = $('[name="lat"]').val();
```

Sometimes it's better to use AJAX query to get some data from DB dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

this will be very simple if you want to write a php code then instead using laravel Blade templating engine you rather prefer to use
 `<?= $data->latitude ?>` 
but on the other hand if the data isnt there you should also check it too .  like using isset() function whether its set or not .

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {<?=  $data->latitude ?>, <?=  $data->longitude ?>} ,
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
```

always preffer to check if the variable is set or not .. hope this will help u in future

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var lat = <?php $data->latitude ?>
var lng = <?php $data->longitude ?>
```

And also do like this

```
var lat = $('#longitude').val();//set value 
var lng = $('#latitude').val();
```

Comment: @WaseemHassan hardcoding PHP inside JS is a terrible practice, never do it.

Answer (score 0):

if your javascript is inside laravel blade this should work

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {
   lat:{{ $data->latitude }}, 
   lng:{{ $data->longitude }}
},
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
```